# DAX formula needed to calculate in missing values

Tags: powerbi, dax

Dataset:

Model:

[image]

Table:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Expected result if different number of SalesPerson filtered:

[image]

Need to calculate "Profit" for SalesPerson bbb, ccc, ddd whichever is filtered.

Profit is proportional to Sales %, but column SalesPerson can be filtered and Sales % depends on how many SalesPerson selected.
Only Profit of SalesPerson aaa is always known.

```
CalculationofSales =
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE (
        SUM ( [Sales] ),
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Sales] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ) )
    )
)
```

Calculation of "Profit" should be:
Total Profit = Sales % of aaa * Profit of aaa

Then Profit of bbb = Sales % of bbb * [Total Profit] (that's where [Total Profit] is incorrect for me.

Comment: How do you calculate profit from Sales?

Comment: It's not directly related. I know Profit of aaa and Sales %. Sales % can change depending on filter on "Salesperson". If only aaa and bbb selected, Sales % of aaa would change to 75%, but profit would still be 1000. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The formula you provided is calculating the Sales % for each SalesPerson based on the sales data.

So first, calculate the Profit per 1% for SalesPerson "aaa

```
ProfitPer1Percent = 
DIVIDE(SUMX(FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[SalesPerson] = "aaa"), 'Table'[Profit]),
       SUMX(FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[SalesPerson] = "aaa"), 'Table'[Sales %]))
```

Then you can then use this value (`ProfitPer1Percent`) to compute the profit for other SalesPersons:

```
CalculatedProfit = 
VAR ProfitPer1Perc = [ProfitPer1Percent]
VAR CurrentSalesPercent = CALCULATE(DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[Sales]), CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]), ALLSELECTED('Table'[SalesPerson]))))
RETURN 
IF(ISBLANK('Table'[Profit]),
   CurrentSalesPercent * ProfitPer1Perc,
   'Table'[Profit])
```

Comment: Profit is not a column, but a measure.

Comment: Hi Amira, Thank you, but I get an error on CalculatedProfit. I updated description, maybe this time it's easier to understand what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you provide more data for Table2? It contains only for data for SalesPerson = aaa

Comment: That's exactly the issue. Only data for SalesPerson = aaa is available in Table2. It there was data for the rest of Salesperson entries, I wouldn't have any issues with calculations.

Comment: And the expected output came from where if you don't have any entries for SalesPersons other than A

Comment: Expected outcome is what I'm trying to calculate. I have profit of aaa and it's proportional to Sales %, so should be possible to calculate profit for other SalesPerson because I have their Sales %, but I just can't figure out how.